# Poor first post audit selection

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I had a first post audit today, and passed it... it was, well, *too* obvious.  And while I realize that this is in part to catch robo reviewers, there can be some things done to improve it for the near-robob poor human choices too.

The audit itself was [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/38976).

[image: How the audit appeared]

**Do not select a first post from a deleted user**

[image: Flag history]

**Do not select a post that the reviewer has previously interacted with**

How to fix?

1. Remove candidate posts for ones that have been flagged (close voted? deleted voted?) by the reviewer .  If there is a filter for first post reviews to show up to reviewers, at least some of this should apply to the selection of the audits.
2. If you do pick a deleted user, pseudo-reinstatiate the gravatar (don't have to get the actual email, even 'user100600@stackexchange.com' would work).

Comment: With all the complaints about and problems with poorly-chosen audits, I think a few that are too easy is a refreshing change of pace. In any case, for any audit that's "too easy," I bet you can find multiple users who failed it

Comment: Audits don't need to be perfect or particularly tricky. They're intended to catch people who really aren't paying attention, so if you passed one because you noticed something about a post, great!

Comment: @AnnaLear its not so much a desire to make them particularly tricky, but rather to make them obvious.  The combination of interacting with the post before *and* a deleted user made it very obvious for me. As noted in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196189/213963 there are *still* too many people doing no action needed or upvotes on obvious spam.