# Review ban reason and warnings

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

When I'm entering reviews on Stack Overflow I'm seeing:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14369458 is a textbook
>   example of a poor question. "No action needed" is completely wrong.
>   Come back in 5 days to continue reviewing.

I'm aware of some audit questions in reviews but after reviewing that one I haven't got any warning that I marked bad question as No action needed. What more I was banned about a week after doing wrong review.

My question is does this message means I was ban by moderator? And why I was banned without any explanation, message and why after a week?

I agree that question is not good quality. Maybe I've missed it maybe haven't understood. But I would expect some warning before banning review. Maybe it is also good idea to show some stats to user: how many wrong reviews I did to allow me analyse and improve my behaviour not just ban. For me such communicate makes me think: why should I care about doing reviews at all? I will just keep my edit privs for those questions which I'm answering and don't care all review queues.

Please don't understand me wrong. I understand I did something wrong but way I was communicated and lack of some stats discourage me in participating in this area at all.

Don't you think user who do some wrong reviews should be warned about it? Got some access to stats about wrong reviews? Maybe it is better to force user to browse his wrong reviews to learn him something not just ban?

Comment: related: [Could we make the review-banned-by-a-mod notice say something more descriptive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196176/could-we-make-the-review-banned-by-a-mod-notice-say-something-more-descriptive)

Comment: ...see also: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: This review (in more than one queue) has come up on mso: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338596/review-suspension-contradictory-recommendation

Comment: Rule of thumb: No Action Needed is _never_ the correct review action.

Comment: It's nice you, of your own free will, decided to donate your time to try to make the site better.  But you don't yet know what is and is not on topic.  It takes a while for an average user to get a good grasp of this.  Months.  Sometimes over a year.  So I'd suggest rather than reviewing, you should spend your time answering questions and making edit improvements (when warranted, which might be a whole other subject). When you feel better about your understanding of what is on topic, go ahead and start reviewing again.

Comment: @Won't probably you're right. Thanks for youe comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a manual ban by a moderator. That is the only way to get a review ban without failing audits.

This is also why you didn't get a warning. Moderators don't have to give warnings to bad reviewers. They can do this, but it would require a moderator message and that leaves a mark on the reviewer's account.
So instead, they ban right away if you're reviewing badly.

It also explains why the review ban came later. Moderators have a lot of work to do, and can't handle everything right away. It is well possible that your reviewing was flagged by someone in the community, and thus brought to the moderator's attention.

We don't have warnings for bad reviews, other than audit failures. Review is quality control; if you do it badly, the system or the moderators stop you right there.
It would be nice if moderators could just warn people about their reviewing, but at least on Stack Overflow, the site is simply too busy for that.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. It is a bit sad but conclusion for me is don't do reviews because you can lose edit privs (even for missclick) which you need to answer questions.

Comment: @Kacper: ... what? No, that's not even slightly correct. You can't be answer-banned for messing up reviews, nor do you lose edit privileges for that either. (Nor do you need2k  editing privileges to answer, obviously.) You lose *reviewing privileges*. That's it. And if you misclick badly enough to be manually review-banned, well, be more careful next time.

Comment: I mean I'm banned from edit or approve edit priv now. Which makes me more difficult to answer when I can't format someone's code. I not mean I can't answer at all :) I shopuld writ which helps to answer not need.

Comment: That's a bit weird. I'm sure I was blocked of doing any edits on posts (even directly) 2-3 days ago and now I can do them. Is it possible?

Comment: @Kacper Review bans and edit bans are separate. If you have an edit ban, you can still review.

Answer (score 9):

> does this message means I was ban by moderator?

Yes, you were manually banned by a moderator when he somehow noticed that review you made (maybe via a flag, maybe be change), this explains the delay.

> why I was banned without any explanation

There is an explanation, in the message itself.

The 5 days review ban **is** the warning. If you'll make bad reviews again after that, you'll get longer bans, up to permanent review ban.

Good luck, and hope you'll pay more attention in future reviews when getting out of the current ban.